# How to change style in the radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, radio-button

I make an content changer with jquery, when you select an other radio button the content change, this is alright! But i have tried change the radio title style when you make the change. but  i'm not getting it

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FelipeMartinin/URU86/)

Another thing. When you change the content, the height of the box change too. I have tried make a fluid motion using the property transition, but don't work =/

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance and have a merry christmas

```
               <form class="my-form-radio">
                    <input data-id="#form-show-item-1" type="radio" name="name" checked /><span class="active"> De Aeroporto para Bairro</span>
                    <input data-id="#form-show-item-2" type="radio" name="name" /><span> De Bairro para Aeroporto</span>
                    <input data-id="#form-show-item-3" type="radio" name="name" /><span> Ida e Volta </span>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your radios in `<label>` . Makes it easier to click since clicking anywhere on label will change the radio

```
<label for="form-show-item-1" class="active">
     <input data-id="#form-show-item-1" type="radio" name="name" checked /> 
      De Aeroporto para Bairro
</label>
```

Then you can target the radio `parent()`

```
$('.my-form-radio input').change(function() {

      var section4 = $(this).attr('data-id');
        $(".my-form-radio label.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        $('.dinamic-form-content').hide();
        $(section4).fadeIn(800);

  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/URU86/5/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/URU86/4/)

```
$('.my-form-radio input').change(function () {

    //console.info(  $(this).attr('href') );
    var section4 = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $(".my-form-radio span").removeClass("active");
    $(this).next().addClass("active");
    $('.dinamic-form-content').hide();
    $(section4).fadeIn(800);

});
```

NOTE: style is not on radio but on span next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require javascript, only css.

```
 input[type=radio] {
            display:none; 
            margin:10px;
        }

    input[type=radio] {
        display:inline-block;
        margin:-2px;
        padding: 4px 12px;
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        border-color: #ddd;
    }

    input[type=radio]:checked { 
       background-image: none;
        background-color:#d0d0d0;
    }
```